# Prove $f(z)$ is identically zero if it has a power series expansion at $0$ which converges in all of C.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Suppose $ f $  has a power series expansion at $0$ which converges in all of C. Suppose also that $ \int_C \mid{f(x+iy)\mid} dxdy <\infty $. Prove $ f $ is identically $0$.

Now I have proved that $f(0) =0$. Can I then claim that by continuity and since C is an open and connected region $f$ will also be zero or is this logic flawed?

Comment: Why not Liouville's theorem?

Comment: Wouldn't that require f(z) to be bounded at all z?

Comment: No, even if there is a zero at $0$ it does not mean that the function is identically zero. The answer should be based on the fact that $\int_C |f(x+iy)|dxdy < \infty$ puts severe constraints on the growth of $f$. Use a Cauchy's estimate type bound to show that any coefficient of $z^n$ in the power series with $n>0$ has to be zero.

Comment: if you fix $w$ and apply Cauchy in an annulus of radiuses $1$ to $2$ centered at $w$, you immediately bound $|f(w)|$ in terms of the integral on the annulus of $|f|$ which is obviously at most the fixed finite $\int_{\mathbb C} \mid{f(x+iy)\mid} dxdy=M$, so you get that $f$ bounded etc

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I actually figured it out.